# Access respective parent object from $('.class').appendTo()

Tags: javascript, jquery, slide

I'm trying to adapt some slideshow code I [found here](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/zKbYzP) to be reusable based on classes.  The first slideshow toggles once, but then there is no other change.  I'm assuming this is due to the use of `$(this).parent()`.  If so, how would I access the respective parent properly? If not, what is going on?

**Edit: To be clear, both boxes contents should change independently!**

```js
$('.widget-slide:first').show();
setInterval(function() {
    $('.widget-slide:first')
        .fadeOut(1000)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .end()
        .appendTo($(this).parent());
}, 2000);
```

```css
.widget-slideshow {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.widget-slide:not(:first-child){
  display: none;
}

.widget-slide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="widget-slideshow">
    <div class="widget-slide">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="widget-slide">
        2
    </div>
    <div class="widget-slide">
        3
    </div>
    <div class="widget-slide">
        4
    </div>
</div>

<div class="widget-slideshow">
    <div class="widget-slide">
        A
    </div>
    <div class="widget-slide">
        B
    </div>
    <div class="widget-slide">
        C
    </div>
    <div class="widget-slide">
        D
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make your code reusable you must use the `each()` function so it will loop through as match slider as you add and make them fiddle in/out :

```
$(".widget-slideshow").find('.widget-slide:first').each(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut(1000)
      .next()
      .fadeIn(1000)
      .end()
      .appendTo($(this).parent());
});
```

#### Working Snippet

```js
$('.widget-slide:first').show();
setInterval(function() {
  $(".widget-slideshow").find('.widget-slide:first').each(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut(1000)
      .next()
      .fadeIn(1000)
      .end()
      .appendTo($(this).parent());
  });
}, 3000);
```

```css
.widget-slideshow {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.widget-slide:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}

.widget-slide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="widget-slideshow">
  <div class="widget-slide">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="widget-slide">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="widget-slide">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="widget-slide">
    4
  </div>
</div>

<div class="widget-slideshow">
  <div class="widget-slide">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="widget-slide">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="widget-slide">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="widget-slide">
    4
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That won't work. The goal is to make the code reusable.  Ideally, I could copy and paste the HTML and make a 3rd show without adding JavaScript.

Comment: Yeah, I just posted a solution using that.  If you can edit your answer to state basically what I asked for is impossible and I'll have to use $.each, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Although it doesn't technically answer my question, this works great.

```js
$('.widget-slide:first').show();
  setInterval(function() {
  $('.widget-slideshow').each(function(i) {
    $(this).find('.widget-slide:first')
      .fadeOut(1000)
      .next()
      .fadeIn(1000)
      .end()
      .appendTo($(this));
    })
}, 2000);
```

```css
.widget-slideshow {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.widget-slide:not(:first-child){
  display: none;
}

.widget-slide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="widget-slideshow">
    <div class="widget-slide">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="widget-slide">
        2
    </div>
    <div class="widget-slide">
        3
    </div>
    <div class="widget-slide">
        4
    </div>
</div>

<div class="widget-slideshow">
    <div class="widget-slide">
        A
    </div>
    <div class="widget-slide">
        B
    </div>
    <div class="widget-slide">
        C
    </div>
    <div class="widget-slide">
        D
    </div>
</div>
```